# customize alt text of an img tag

Tags: html, css, jquery, image

To display a hint when my user hovers his mouse over an image 
`<img src="image" alt="product code 000000">`

However, the default alt text always displays on the right of my cursor. 
Is there any way I can move the displayed mini popup to the left of the mouse cursor ???

**Update** Thank you everyone for your replies.

Comment: This is impossible as the tooltip is generated by the OS and not the browser/html. You'll have to use javascript to develop your own. But this is a commonly seen thing and it might not be a good idea to change something.

Comment: That's a known bug in Internet Explorer. The text in the `alt` attribute should *not* be displayed if the image loads successfully. No other browser exhibits such behaviour. You possibly want the `title` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the yellow tooltip ? You can't. But you can make your own using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip is the Title element, the alt is the text that appears when the image is not visible. You cannot format the title element, however as has been mentioned you can add in a custom tooltip. I like using the [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) tooltips which are easy to get working for a start.

Then you would be able to change the CSS to move it over to the left.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of javascript tooltip scripts around that can do that for you. By the way, in most browsers the tooltip displays on title="" attribute, not alt.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't but you can create your own using `css` and/or `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a toolbox in css

```
img{position:relative;}
img:hover::before{
  content:attr(alt);
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;

}
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CSS-TECHS/#Alt